# Perfect forwarding function vs perfect forwarding constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I can't figure out why this doesn't work:

```
template<class T> void makeNew(T&& func)
{
    function<void()> p = forward<T>(func);  
}

class POP
{
private:
    function<void()> fu;
public:
    template<typename T> POP(T&& func) : fu(forward<T>(func)) {}
};

void Test(){}
```

now to the code:

```
makeNew(Test); //compiles  (1)
makeNew(&Test); //compiles (2)
makeNew(function<void()>(Test)); //compiles (3)
POP pop(&Test); //compiles (4)
POP popp(Test); //doesn't compile (5)
POP pp(function<void()>(Test)); //doesn't compile (6)
```

Why 1,3 compiles and 5,6 doesn't compile ?

for (5) I get this error:

`error C2664: 'POP::POP<void(void)>(T (__cdecl &&))' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'void (__cdecl *)(void)' to 'void (__cdecl &&)(void)'`

for (6) I get this error:

`'POP pp(std::tr1::function<_Fty>)': prototyped function not called (was a variable definition intended?)`

Using VS2010.

Comment: Can you do a much better job of explaining what you see than "doesn't compile" and "doesn't work"?

Comment: Profanity filter in your compiler?  Speaking of which, what compiler and version?  Tested your stuff on a different one like ideone in a sscce?  What error are you getting, exactly?

Comment: VS2010 does not have that much [support for c++11](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Actually, it compiles just fine [in GCC 4.8](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c38fb5597c80557), [in GCC 4.7](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/16f4d69b82b6d90d), [in GCC 4.6](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5abe69e32c28f9a), [in clang trunk r198621 (pre-3.5)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e40b58a88f021138), and in Visual Studio 2012.

If #5 doesn't compile in MSVS2010, then it's buggy (not unusual at all for C++11 features in that toolchain).

Note that you are being warned that #6 you declared a function rather than an object. Perhaps, then, your second error is in some later code that doesn't realise you fell into the [Most Vexing Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) (though you didn't show us any such code).